# pandas concat('outer') not doing union?

Tags: python, join, pandas

It looks `pandas.concat` is doing 'left outer' join instead of just union the indexes. Seems a bug to me but maybe I'm missing something obvious.

```
    import pandas
    import pandas.util.testing as put
    ts1 = put.makeTimeSeries()
    ts2 = put.makeTimeSeries()[::2]
    ts3 = put.makeTimeSeries()[::3]
    ts4 = put.makeTimeSeries()[::4]

    ## to join with union
    ## these two are of different length!
    pandas.concat([ts1,ts2], join='outer', axis = 1) 
    pandas.concat([ts2,ts1], join='outer', axis = 1)
```

Any idea how can I get the full union (as they do claim by using join='outer' on the pandas document)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug. Opened an issue here:

http://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/1719

(Please use GitHub for pandas bug reports)

Comment: Alright. Thanks Wes. Any idea how I can get the full union before the bug is fixed later?