# python pandas (horizontal) concat error with timeseries of the same name

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, concatenation

(pandas 0.10.1)

Simple example down here.

```
import pandas
import pandas.util.testing as PUT
ts1 = PUT.makeTimeSeries(3)       ## not zero
ts2 = PUT.makeTimeSeries(3) * 0.0 ## zeros
ts1.name = 'ts'
ts2.name = 'ts'
df = pandas.concat([ts1,ts2], axis = 1)
print df

            ts  ts
2000-01-03  -0  -0
2000-01-04   0   0
2000-01-05   0   0
```

Or reversely,

```
df = pandas.concat([ts2,ts1], axis = 1)

                  ts        ts
2000-01-03  0.615385  0.615385
2000-01-04 -0.881817 -0.881817
2000-01-05  2.354081  2.354081
```

Vertical concat is fine

```
df = pandas.concat([ts2,ts1], axis = 0)

2000-01-03   -0.000000
2000-01-04    0.000000
2000-01-05    0.000000
2000-01-03    0.615385
2000-01-04   -0.881817
2000-01-05    2.354081
Name: ts
```

The original ts1 and ts2 are not overwritten though

```
print ts1

2000-01-03    0.615385
2000-01-04   -0.881817
2000-01-05    2.354081
Freq: B, Name: ts

print ts2

2000-01-03   -0
2000-01-04    0
2000-01-05    0
Freq: B, Name: ts
```

btw, the result is correct if you concat two DF with same column names

Comment: It's a bug. See here:

[Already asked question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761884/pandas-concatouter-not-doing-union

Comment: Hmm, the linked question is also asked by me. That bug I think is fixed in version 0.9.

Comment: Then you should really open a bug report. BTW in 0.8.0 it is running.

Comment: but... see [Wes' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11769819/1240268): "please **use [github for filing bugs**](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues)".

Comment: lol, seems you guys really work hard to keep the reputation of pandas on SO by blocking bug reports.

1. If you are careful enough, you will realise this is not a duplicate question

2. SO in general does want bug reports

3. Wes's word is not law to me, but maybe it is to you